# Custom Class Operator wrapping to v8 Engine Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

Hello I am using the Google's v8 JavaScript engine and I have a straight forward question in regards to doing this in the C++ environment (NOT JS Environment).

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to create an object that acts like a Vector in a game environment, in this case it has a parameter of 3 floating points.

in C++ this function has operator+ and so I can do something like...

Example 1: (C++)

```
Vector vector(5,5,5);
Vector vector2(10,10,10);

Vector final = vector + vector2;
```

Which will result become 15,15,15  of course...

Now the biggest question is how can I make it so that when I execute in JavaScript and expose Vector as the same exact object above and have

Example 2: (JS)

```
var l = new Vector(5,5,5);
var r = new Vector(10,10,10);

var final = l + r;
```

in JavaScript this would typically execute the valueOf, and I could perform a similar concept of doing "Fake Operator" aka using this article

http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html

The biggest question is how would I go about this?

I am thinking of creating an Add function so that I can wrap the left + right in C++ then have a function calling it vector.add(15,15,15) or vector.add(right);  and will also have Vector.add(left, right); in "JS" environment though

Now what I want to be able to do is doing the Example 2 which is JavaScript.  So when I do l + r; it will invoke the method in C++ internally calling the Add method.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: So you want to call C++ function from JavaScript? I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Actually that part is easy =).  What I am trying to do is make it so that I can use the javascript operators aka when you add a number to another number its built into v8 engine.  I am trying to figure out how to make it so that I can apply the same concept for specific custom objects exposed to JavaScript

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have operator overloading and v8 doesn't give you api hooks for + operator, it is simply impossible

Comment: @Esailija as for the v8 doesn't giving me api hooks for operators such as +, -, *, / and saying that it is simply impossible that is reasonable but if your saying that I cannot do it with JavaScript then I hate to break the news to you but it can be done I posted an article that they call "fake" operators that can be done to make it work via javascript.  I guess the idea is to do the same fake operator concept all in the v8 C++ environment, I probably could even do it faster in the C++ environment than the javascript.

Comment: @Benjamin no the article doesn't allow you to overload operators, not even fake overload. Because you can only return a primitive from `valueOf` for starters...

Comment: @Esailija yes that does make sense, in a concept it is called fake operators =) I've tested that entire article and it does work

Comment: yes the very specific examples in the article work, that doesn't mean you have general overloading capabilities where implementing what you ask for is possible. It  just means that the specific examples work. Even if you could return an object from valueOf, you would have no way of knowing how the valueOf was invoked.